the difference between two expressions 一直对自己坚持 and 一直坚持自己
I want to know what is the difference between "一直对自己坚持" and "一直坚持自己"
and are both of them correct in terms of grammar?

（从感觉上）我觉得「一直对自己坚持」不通顺不合语法，「一直坚持自己」是可以的。然而，我们一般使用「一直坚持自我」或者「一直坚持自己的梦想/见解/主张」，而不使用「一直坚持自己」比如「他在中年时一直坚持自己」这样的表述。

"一直对自己的坚持感到自傲" and  "一直坚持自己的信念" both are valid phrases. We need more of your thoughts.

感觉两句话都有语病，我在百度上只搜到了“一直坚持自我”。

自己相当于myself，自我相当于ego，明显意思不相同。

Basically, both of them are incorrect. "一直对自己坚持" makes no sense, and "一直坚持自己" lacks a subject. Let's break them down into more digestible pieces:

一直: continuously; all along; straight (more of "直").
对[自己]: to oneself.
坚持: to stand one's grounds; insist; stick to.

Now, if we assemble the above parts together:

In "一直对自己坚持", the rough part-to-part translation will be: "continuously to oneself, (noun/pronoun) insisted"?! That isn't quite right. Actually, in Chinese it's even more weird than in the English translation. What you meant by that was probably: "一直坚持自己的 (noun)" or "一直獨自坚持 (noun)", or omit the "坚持" part and instead use "告訴" as a replacement (this, I think, is closest to the intended meaning of the original incorrect sentence): "一直告訴自己". In any case, the original sentence is completely wrong.
In "一直坚持自己", the rough translation will be "continuously insisted oneself"?! The problem here is that you cannot "insist oneself"; i.e., you cannot insist a person, because that makes no sense. The main issue is that the sentence lacks a subject. An easy fix would be to add a noun at the end of the sentence: "一直坚持自己的主張" ("continuously insisted their proposition") or similar.

In summary, since both of them are incorrect in their current form, the correct meaning are the same. Actually, there's basically only one way to write the sentence, that is "一直坚持自己的 (noun)".

一直坚持自己的意见: stubborn
固执成见，汉语成语，
固执成见，a Chinese saying,
拼音是gù zhí chéng jiàn，
pinyin as gù zhí chéng jiàn，
意思是顽固地坚持自己的意见，
(its) meaning is stubbornly, obstinately clinging to ones opinion
不肯改变。
refusing to agree.
出自茅盾《子夜》
From Máo Dùn 《Midnight》
一直坚持自己: principled
一直坚持自己的意思是指不放弃自己的原则和立场，
Always cling to ones own opinion means not (willing) to renounce ones principles or doctrine and point of view,
即使面对外界的压力和诱惑也要保持自我。
Even when confronted with pressure and enticements from the outside world, still one maintains ones own principles.

Both sentences are wrong.
坚持 is a verb, the object of 坚持 (persist/ firmly hold) would always be an action or idea, something that can be persisted, held, or stuck to
Example:
坚持罷工行動 - Continue the strike (persistently go on strike)
坚持已見 - Stick to your guns (persistently holding your opinion)

坚持自己 = Persist oneself (X)

对自己坚持 = Persist toward oneself (X)

坚持自己的立場 = Stand your ground (O)

对自己的立場坚持 = Stick to your own position (O)


